# AsyncTask and Android threading: how to get it right ?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, mobile

I am firing off an AsyncTask to fetch images via HttpClient.

Via DDMS in eclipse, the view shows that the AsyncTask runs and then hangs around.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMFjf.jpg) is a screenshot of the DDMS threads view.

Should the AsyncTask #1 thread disappear or is it benign ? What does the status *wait* mean anyway ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really worried, over ride onPostExecute like this

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("I am finished");
 }
```

If your thread is finished, you don't have to worry about it. It's in Android's hands now.

I suspect what's happening is your thread is done but Android doesn't reclaim the memory because it doesn't need it yet.

Comment: More specifically, AsyncTask uses a thread pool, so those threads will sit in the pool until the process is closed.

Comment: Hi Commonsware, do you think it has any impact on performance?